# How to ignore failed linear regression in a big dataset?

Tags: r

I'm running a "lm" regression to a large dataset by groups.
The problem I'm facing is that for the groups where the analysis failed for reasons such as: no variation in the data, or the levels of one of the factors is = 1, or missing values ... it totally stops the creation of my output dataframe.

Can anyone help me by suggesting a solution to this problem?

My datasets consists on 4 columns:

- Y: response
- X1: 1st explanatory variable
- X2: 2nd explanatory variable
- Location: is the column to group my data, so lm runs by Location.

Here is the code I'm using to get Predicted and Srudentized-residuals by observation:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

output <- as.data.frame(dataset)
output$Y <- as.numeric(output$Y)
output$X1 <- as.factor(output$X1)
output$X2 <- as.factor(output$X2)

df <- output %>%
group_by(location) %>% 
do(cbind(location = .$location, lm(Y ~ X1 + X2, data = .) %>% augment))
```

When I run this code on some locations that I know previously are OK, it works fine, but once I run it on all locations, I got an error message.

Answer (score 1):

How are you running you regressions? without any data or code related to what you are trying to do, it is impossible to reproduce what you are experiencing. Here is an example of a group of regressions where some groups have NA and some are one observation. No errors occur:

```r
library(tidyverse)

#example
df <- mtcars |>
  add_row(tibble(mpg = c(32, NA),
                 hp = c(12, NA),
                 cyl = c(1, 6)))

df |>
  nest(data = -cyl) |>
  mutate(lm = map(data, ~lm(mpg~hp, data = .x) |> broom::tidy())) |>
  unnest(lm) |>
  select(-data)
#> # A tibble: 8 x 6
#>     cyl term        estimate std.error statistic     p.value
#>   <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1     6 (Intercept) 20.7        3.30       6.26    0.00153  
#> 2     6 hp          -0.00761    0.0266    -0.286   0.786    
#> 3     4 (Intercept) 36.0        5.20       6.92    0.0000693
#> 4     4 hp          -0.113      0.0612    -1.84    0.0984   
#> 5     8 (Intercept) 18.1        2.99       6.05    0.0000574
#> 6     8 hp          -0.0142     0.0139    -1.02    0.326    
#> 7     1 (Intercept) 32        NaN        NaN     NaN        
#> 8     1 hp          NA         NA         NA      NA
```